# How would I make a String which includes brackets? - java

Tags: java, string

So when i try

```
String string1 = "{"needs_reward":false,"has_voted":false,"sites":[{"id":3922,"name":"RuneTopList","has_voted":false,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=3922"},{"id":4613,"name":"RuneLocus","has_voted":false,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=4613"},{"id":4339,"name":"UltimatePrivateServers","has_voted":true,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=4339"},{"id":4340,"name":"TopG","has_voted":true,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=4340"},{"id":4341,"name":"MMORPGToplist","has_voted":true,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=4341"},{"id":4622,"name":"Rune-Server","has_voted":true,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=4622"},{"id":4623,"name":"GTop100","has_voted":true,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=4623"},{"id":4828,"name":"GamingTopList","has_voted":true,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=4828"},{"id":4829,"name":"RSPS-List","has_voted":true,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=4829"},{"id":4861,"name":"Top100Arena","has_voted":true,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=4861"}]}"
```

I get errors because it contains brackets, how would i set this as a string?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your problem is with the quotes. Change each " to \"

Comment: Except the first and the last quote escape all the other quotes to \"

Comment: [This little tool](http://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score 10):

The brackets aren't problem - the quotes are. For example, this is fine:

```
String braces = "{}";
```

The quote (`"`) is used to terminate a string, so you need to escape it with a `\`:

```
String sentence = "My son said, \"Hello, world!\" and then ran away.";
```

That creates a string of:

```
My son said, "Hello, world!" and then ran away.
```

If you need a `\` in your text, you need to escape that, too - but not forward slashes:

```
String slashes = "Backslash: \\ and forward slash: /";
```

You don't need to escape single quotes within a string, but you *do* need to escape them within a character literal (as `'` would otherwise be the end of the literal):

```
String text = "I don't need a backslash";
char c = '\'';
```

I would encourage you not to store a lot of text directly in your code anyway though - it's generally more readable if you store it as text files which you load the data from at execution time.

Comment: i am a big fan of yours! :)

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an example:

```
String str = "Hello \"joe\"!";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a json object, formatting it better. Why don't you use some JSON builders to create String from Object. And have this object depicting what you see here.

Jackson is a good api.

```
class Reward {
    boolean needs_reward = false;
    boolean has_voted = false;
    List<Sites> sites = new ArrayList();
}

class Sites {
   int id;
   String name;
   boolean has_voted;
   String vote_url;
}
```

--

```
"{"needs_reward":false,"has_voted":false,
"sites":[
    {"id":3922,"name":"RuneTopList","has_voted":false,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=3922"},
    {"id":4613,"name":"RuneLocus","has_voted":false,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=4613"},
    {"id":4339,"name":"UltimatePrivateServers","has_voted":true,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=4339"},
    {"id":4340,"name":"TopG","has_voted":true,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=4340"},
    {"id":4341,"name":"MMORPGToplist","has_voted":true,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=4341"},
    {"id":4622,"name":"Rune-Server","has_voted":true,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=4622"},
    {"id":4623,"name":"GTop100","has_voted":true,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=4623"},
    {"id":4828,"name":"GamingTopList","has_voted":true,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=4828"},
    {"id":4829,"name":"RSPS-List","has_voted":true,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=4829"},
    {"id":4861,"name":"Top100Arena","has_voted":true,"vote_url":"http://api.runetoplist.com/vote/out?siteid=4861"}]
}"
```